# Do multiple org.gradle.jvmargs entries overwrite each other?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Looked everywhere but couldn't find an answer; if there are two or more entries of `org.gradle.jvmargs` entries in `gradle.properties`, for example,

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dorg.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout=120000 -Dorg.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=120000
```

would the second entry overwrite the first? (in my particular setup it would take too long to test hence this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as i know , and tested right now , Yes
The second will overwrite the first value .

I have tested with artifactory userName and the second one overwite the first value .

and you can check [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

> org.gradle.jvmargs=(JVM arguments)
> Specifies the JVM arguments used for the Gradle Daemon. The setting is particularly useful for configuring JVM memory settings for build performance. This does not affect the JVM settings for the Gradle client VM.

That there is no special treat for this kind of value in gradle.properties file .

Finally , and just to make sure , You go to the build.gradle folder , open cmd and type  `gradle properties` this will show you all the properties that are set for this build .